# C++ Object pointer issue

Tags: c++, pointers, object

The intent of the code below is to define a self-managеable polygon class that consists of triangle objects, that consist of point objects.

Having the polygon built out of triangles suggests that all triangles in the polygon are connected, more precisely, each triangle relates to the one prior to it. Hence my decision to create 3 point objects in the triangle class and 3 point object pointers that refer to the former and when needed, point to another triangle's points.

I have however been stuck on the following - the point object pointers don't seem to point to a valid target despite them being properly assigned to an address in the constructor of the triangle class.

-header file-

```
struct Point {
    float X, Y;

    Point( const float x, const float y );
    Point operator+ ( Point &p );
    void set( const float x, const float y );
};

class Triangle {
    Point point_a_, point_b_, point_c_;
    float distance_ab_, distance_bc_,
                distance_ac_, area_;

    void calculateArea();
    void calculateDistance(  );

    protected:
    Point *point_a_ptr_, *point_b_ptr_, *point_c_ptr_;

    public:
    Triangle( Point a, Point b, Point c );
    void  setDimensions( Point a, Point b, Point c );
    float getArea() const;
    float getDistance( const short index ) const;
    void  varPoint( const short index, Point* point );
    void  varPoint( const short index, Point point );
    Point varPoint( const short index ) const;

    friend class Polygon;
};

class Polygon {
    std::vector<Triangle> triangles_;
    int edges_;

    public:
    Polygon( const int edges );
    Triangle getTriangle( const int index ) const;
    void varPoint( const int index, Point point );
    Point varPoint( const int index ) const;
    void varEdges( const int edges );
    short varEdges() const;
};
```

-cpp file-

```
Point::Point( const float x = 0, const float y = 0 ) {
  X = x;
  Y = y;
}

void Point::set( const float x, const float y ) {
  X = x;
  Y = y;
}

Point Point::operator+ ( Point &p ) {
  Point calculated_point;
  calculated_point.X = X + p.X;
  calculated_point.Y = Y + p.Y;  
  return calculated_point;
}

Triangle::Triangle( Point a = Point( 0, 0 ),
                    Point b = Point( 0, 0 ),
                                        Point c = Point( 0, 0 ) ) {
    point_a_.set( 0, 0 );//speculation
    point_b_.set( 100, 0 );//speculation
    point_c_.set( 100, 200 );//speculation
    point_a_ptr_ = &point_a_;
    point_b_ptr_ = &point_b_;
    point_c_ptr_ = &point_c_;
    this->setDimensions( a, b, c );
}

void Triangle::calculateArea() {
    distance_bc_ = ::distance( point_b_, point_c_ );
    distance_ac_ = ::distance( point_c_, point_a_ );
    distance_ab_ = ::distance( point_a_, point_b_ );
    float p = ( distance_ab_ +
                distance_bc_ +
                            distance_ac_ ) / 2.0;
  area_ = sqrt( p * ( p - distance_ab_ ) *
                        ( p - distance_bc_ ) *
                                        ( p - distance_ac_ ) );
    return;
}

float Triangle::getDistance( const short index ) const {
    float distance = 0;

    switch( index ) {
        case 0: distance = distance_ab_;
                break;
        case 1: distance = distance_bc_;
                break;
        case 2: distance = distance_ac_;
                break;
        default: break;
    }

    return distance;
}

void Triangle::setDimensions( Point a, Point b, Point c ) {
    *point_a_ptr_ = a;
    *point_b_ptr_ = b;
    *point_c_ptr_ = c;
    this->calculateArea();
}

float Triangle::getArea() const {
    return area_;
}

Point Triangle::varPoint( const short index ) const {
    Point return_point( 0, 0 );

    switch( index ) {
        case 0: return_point = *point_a_ptr_;
                break;
        case 1: return_point = *point_b_ptr_;
                break;
        case 2: return_point = *point_c_ptr_;
                break;
        default: break;
    }
    return return_point;
}

void Triangle::varPoint( const short index, Point point ) {
    switch( index ) {
        case 0: point_a_ = point;
                break;
        case 1: point_b_ = point;
                break;
        case 2: point_c_ = point;
                break;
        default: break;
    }
    return ;
}

void Triangle::varPoint( const short index, Point* point ) {
    switch( index ) {
        case 0: point_a_ptr_ = point;
                break;
        case 1: point_b_ptr_ = point;
                break;
        case 2: point_c_ptr_ = point;
                break;
        default: break;
    }
    return ;
}

Polygon::Polygon( const int edges = 3 ) {
    edges_ = 0;
    this->varEdges( edges );
}

Triangle Polygon::getTriangle( const int index ) const {
    if( index < 0 || index >= triangles_.size() ) return Triangle();
    return triangles_[index];
}

void Polygon::varEdges( const int edges ) {
    if( edges < 3 || edges == edges_ ) return;
    triangles_.assign( edges - 2, Triangle( Point( 0, 0 ), Point( 30, 0 ), Point( 30, 15 ) ) );

    edges_ = edges;
    return ;
}

short Polygon::varEdges() const {
    return edges_;
}

void Polygon::varPoint( const int index, Point point ) {
    if( index > edges_ - 1 ) return;
    if( index < edges_ - 2 )
        triangles_[index].varPoint( 0, point );
    else
      triangles_[triangles_.size() - 1].varPoint(edges_ - index, point);
    return ;
}

Point Polygon::varPoint( const int index ) const {
    Point return_point( 0, 0 );
    if( index < 0 || index > edges_ - 1 ) return return_point;
    if( index < edges_ - 2 )
        return_point = triangles_[index].varPoint(0);
    else 
        return_point = triangles_[triangles_.size() - 1].varPoint(edges_ - index);

    return return_point;
}
```

Furthermore, if I change the triangle's point mutator function to modify the object refered to by the pointer, as shown below (and as the original intention is), the program crashes.

```
void Triangle::varPoint( const short index, Point point ) {
        switch( index ) {
            case 0: *point_a_ptr_ = point;
                    break;
            case 1: *point_b_ptr_ = point;
                    break;
            case 2: *point_c_ptr_ = point;
                    break;
            default: break;
        }
        return ;
    }
```

This is why I concluded the pointers must point to an invalid target.

All in all, setting the points of a triangle either does nothing( when later accessed, points are 0, 0 ) or crashes the program( when object pointers are used ). If pointers are omitted, the value of the points is correctly set and returned. Code operating with polygons is shown below:

```
Polygon polygon;

polygon.varEdges(4);
polygon.varPoint( 0, 0, 0 );
polygon.varPoint( 1, 400, 200 );
polygon.varPoint( 2, 400, 300 );
polygon.varPoint( 3, 300, 400 );

glBegin( GL_POLYGON );
  glColor4f( red_/255.0, green_/255.0, blue_/255.0, alpha_ );
  for( int i = 0; i < polygon.varEdges(); i++ )
    glVertex2f( polygon.varPoint(i).X, polygon.varPoint(i).Y );
glEnd();
```

I can't figure out where the error is. Apologies if the post is too lengthy.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using pointer member variables in your `Triangle` class?  You have the object assigned already -- my quick look at your code suggests that those pointer member variables are unnecessary.

Comment: If you copy a `Triangle` class (and you do), you'll have pointers in one object pointing at members of another object.

Comment: I've specified in the thread that as the polygon class consists of numerous triangles, it needs to set two of triangle[n]'s points to refer to two of triangle[n-1]'s points, excluding the first triangle.

Comment: @aschepler Where exactly do you mean?

Comment: Narrow it down. This is too much code.

Comment: @aschepler You are using `std::vector<Triangle>`.  Copies will be made using this container.  Second, your design is inherently going to have issues.  Have you considered using `std::shared_ptr`, instead of raw pointer usage?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That was the point itself, to have default objects and have the ability to have them refer to other objects when needed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So it is specific to the vector class usage? Will the shared pointer prevent such mishaps?

Comment: When you put objects into a `vector`, you don't have any control over their address anymore. Any pointers you create to those objects or members of those objects can be rendered invalid on any number of conditions, most notably by adding to the vector. The only way `shared_ptr` would help is if the vector contained those `shared_ptr` rather than the object itself.

Comment: So how do you suggest this particular issue can be overcome?

Comment: Does it also follow that any use of a pointer in an object contained in a vector object is strictly invalid?

Comment: @user203432  Change this: `Point *point_a_ptr_, *point_b_ptr_, *point_c_ptr_` to this: `std::shared_ptr<Point> point_a_ptr_, point_b_ptr_, point_c_ptr_`  That will get rid of the copying issue.  But you need to ask yourself --  is this the intent of the design,  where a pointer to a `Point` is shared between objects?  The name "shared_ptr" means what it implies.  In addition, the lifetime of the shared pointer is determined by the last Triangle that owns it (and gets destroyed).  Again, if this is ok with you, then that is an option.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're right, a remodel of the design might be the best solution. Regardless, this detail of the vector class, it seems to me, is quite a setback. Thank you for the useful info and and the well explained situation!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just found this article a couple of days ago, maybe it would apply here: [std::shared_ptr's secret constructor](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/shared-ptr-secret-constructor.html).